# Searching a Database file table for files in a folder path using SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2013

I am fairly new to SQL programming and I need some help. I am working on creating a little MS Access 2013 report that will dig through an SQL 2008 database's tables that hold folder path information for files and count the number of new files put in over the previous 7 days. I have the coding in place to do the counting, but I'm having trouble with the code to go through the folder id's subfolders to find those files that meet the data range criteria. 
There are two tables, one is a documents table that holds the documents metadata, and another table that folds folder information. I'm sure I will have to provide an inner join clause to put the two tables together in order to make this work.

One table contains a column called 'parentno'. It contains the numeric folder id, or folder number which is how the folders are named in the storage area for files. It has a column titled 'projectno' which contains folder ids of other folders, some of which are subfolders of the specific 'parentno' that I am referencing in my where clause. Another table has a column called 'file name' which is obviously, the file name. It also has a column titled 'projectno' which contains the name of the folder the file resides in.

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please [edit] it to show the structure of each table (column names and types) and some representative sample data so we know what you have to work with.

Comment: Save yourself a bunch of time and don't use Access, stick to SQL

Comment: I edited my post. the columns are numeric data types and the file name column is varchar. And example of a field in the parentno column would be simply a 5 to 6 digit number. Same for the projectno (which is another column for folder names, not project numbers as the column title may suggest.